# New Firefox does open the webpage of a notification

Tags: windows, firefox

I use desktop notification of GMail with Firefox.
Up to the latest update, this worked quite well.
If a new mail came in, it showed the notification.
If I clicked the notification a new Browser popup opened, showing the mail, leaving the rest of the desktop unmodified.

Now with the new Firefox if click on the notification, the main Firefox window is shifted to the foreground and the tab with GMail selected.
This is absolutely undesired behaviour.
I don't want to lose the program I have in foreground or change the tab I'm currently looking at in the main Firefox window.

Is this a regression? Is this a new feature? Can this be configured?

Comment: According to the [release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/29.0.1/releasenotes/), that's by design as of version `29.0.1`: "Clicking on a W3C Web Notification will switch to the originating tab." The change was made to fix [bug 853972](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=853972). Short of downgrading the browser, there doesn't seem to be any way to revert back to the previous behavior.

Comment: Bummer, that's a real regression in my opinion. If you would post this as answer instead of comment, I would be able to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Desktop notifications

According to the official release notes, that's by design as of version 29.0:

> Clicking on a W3C Web Notification will switch to the originating tab
>
> <sub>Source: [Firefox Notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/29.0/releasenotes/)</sub>

The change was made to fix a bug:

> I had the Firefox window open and focused, and I received a desktop notification that originated from a background tab. I clicked on the notification expecting it to switch to the originating tab, but nothing happened.
>
> When the user clicks on a notification we should focus the originating tab.
>
> <sub>Source: [Bug 853972 - Clicking on a desktop notification should switch to the notifying tab](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=853972)</sub>

Short of downgrading the browser, there doesn't seem to be any way to revert back to the previous behavior.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1009190 was opened to improve the situation